# Loader won't start until after process is complete

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to start a loader to show that I have a process going on.  Converting a kml file to geojson.  The converting part works fine.  Larger kml files take longer to convert and I want to show that my web page is doing something while it's converting the file.  I have this:

```
 function convertFunction() {

    loader.style.display = "block";
    if(format.value = "kml"){
         out.value = JSON.stringify(toGeoJSON["kml"]((new DOMParser()).parseFromString(input.value, 'text/xml')), null, 4);
    }
};
```

I'm used to working with Android and when I order my processes like that, it usually starts the first one first.

Why does my loader not start until after my file is converted and placed into my out text view?  How can I get it to work the way I want it to?

I'm not uploading the file to a server first.  I'm reading the text from the file, placing the text in a text view(input), getting the text from the input, convert and put new text in the output text view.  Then last button to create the geojson file and download it.

Comment: It sounds like your tieing up the UI thread doing your parsing. So it starts loading the image, then the thread gets blocked doing the parsing, then it finishes showing the image after the parsing is complete. Not sure the solution but maybe trigger your parsing once the image has loaded, somehow

Comment: The code makes no sense at all. You are mixing assignment with comparison and your code uses methods that are completwly unknown to me. And its still unclear how the code is related to your description.

Comment: I think the if has a typo `format.value = "kml"` should be `format.value == "kml"`. Unclear if that's the issue

Comment: Sorry.  It's fixed.  I really have no idea how that title got like that.

Comment: Liam I tried that.  Also tried changing the code around to use != To check that the value wasn't empty.  It's not the issue.  It still preforms that action inside the if like it's supposed to.  Just have issue with the loader not starting before that process completes

Comment: I mean it is **an** issue. Your if is invalid as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your loader isn't showing is that your conversion process is *blocking code*. This means that it will hold up the main thread (the UI thread) until the conversion process is done. The loader will never be shown because the conversion will already be done before the browser has a chance to show it.

**A possible solution:**

Use a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to carry out the conversion process on a separate thread. This will keep your UI thread free so that your loader can display and animate.

**Another possible (simpler) workaround:**

Display something on the page to indicate that the conversion process is going on, and use `setTimeout` to delay the conversion process just enough to allow the page to update. Note that you wouldn't be able to show any sort of animation during the conversion in this case because the blocked UI thread would prevent it from animating.

```
function convertFunction() {

    if(format.value === "kml"){
        loadingMessage.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function () {
            out.value = JSON.stringify(toGeoJSON["kml"]((new DOMParser()).parseFromString(input.value, 'text/xml')), null, 4);
            loadingMessage.style.display = 'none';

            // run any code that would use out.value
        }, 100);
    }
};
```

Comment: Awesome.  I just found and was reading up on set time out.  I used it and it worked.  Even the loader animation.  I'm guessing if files are even larger, the animation wont work like you said?

Comment: @jamesburnison Yes, I believe that the animation will stop if the blocking code (your conversion) takes a long time.